# I am not able to add elements to end of a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am not able to add elements to the end of a single Linked List. I have tried looking other questions but I am not able to find a solution.

The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
   int data;
   struct node* next;
};

void PushE(struct node** head,int data);

int main(){

  struct node* a = NULL;
  PushE(&a,3);
  PushE(&a,4);
}

void PushE(struct node** headRef, int data){


  struct node* current = *headRef;
  struct node* nNode;
  nNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  nNode->data = data;
  nNode->next= NULL;

  if(current == NULL)
     current = nNode;
  else{
    while(current->next != NULL)
       current = current->next;

  current->next = nNode;
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me implement this.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Where is `struct node` defined?

Comment: I wonder how copy-paste changes the signature..... something from the middle of the statement....

Comment: @SouravGhosh that must be a copy-paste mistake too :)

Comment: Weird clipboard eating up characters!

Answer (score 4):

Problem is here:

```
if(current == NULL)
    current = nNode; // <--
```

How did you get current?

```
struct node* current = *headRef;
```

Current here is a *copy* of the pointer headRef pointed to!

You need to assign to `*headRef` directly.

Answer (score 2):

In this if statement

```
if(current == NULL)
   current = nNode;
```

there is changed local variable current. The pointer pointed to by head is not changed. So the original list will be unchanged after exiting the function.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
int PushE( struct node ** head, int data );

// ...

int PushE( struct node ** head, int data )
{
    struct node *nNode = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = nNode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        nNode->data = data;
        nNode->next = NULL;

        while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = nNode;
    }

    return success;
}
```